# How to use tor with firefox data?

Tags: firefox, tor

I have a bunch of add-ons in my firefox and now I want to use tor.
but installing them on tor browser is not a good idea.
also I want my history and ... on tor too.
so is there a way to use tor with firefox or import full firefox data on tor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to vet your plugins and addons very very very carefully when considering what can or cannot be safely used with TOR. Most folks just recommend using no plugins/addons whatsoever.

The biggest weakness in tor is client the end point. it does no good to anonymize your traffic if your flash client is serving up persistent cookies telling everyone who you are, or your maps plugin is leaking for geolocation lookups, or your search plugins are leaking dns lookup data to your ISP, essentially anouncing "this is the sensitive material I'm looking at". In those cases that your traffic is anonymously routed and encrypted, and leaving an unmonitored exit node in another country does NOTHING for your anonymity.

use the TOR live CD when possible. the configuration is as close to guaranteed as you are likely to get, and it prevents you from mixing activities that REQUIRE anonymity with those that do not. This, in itself, solves the biggest vulnerability in TOR.

Now, all that said, you can always install [TOR client on your host](http://netforbeginners.about.com/od/peersharing/f/installtor.htm), and use the FF extension [TOR Button](https://www.torproject.org/torbutton/) or Foxy Proxy or in-enumerable other proxy apps to toggle tor usage on or off. just remember, tor may not be doing you a bit of good in that configuration. This is exactly why they primarily release tor as part of the browser bundle. otherwise how will you know you aren't leaking all the info you want to protect?

Comment: isn't tor start a simple proxy port like psiphon?

Comment: thats kinda exactly the problem. proxies are application scope entites, but to be anonymous you need a system level proxy. since you can't configure one without advanced networking equipment, its much better to use the live cd

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't checked the documentation, it seems as if the Tor Browser Bundle uses a patched version of Firefox.[(source)](https://www.torproject.org/torbutton/).

As such, you can try to copy the Firefox profiles from one place to another. [Here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox) is more information on Firefox profiles, but essentially it would be as easy to copy and paste, and altering the profile.ini to reflect the change.

If you want to use Firefox and the patched version at the same time with the same profile... I would say to use some sort of soft/hardlink, but that is another story.

Comment: I tried to copy-paste but nothing happens.